# "Conduct a project" or "complete a project", or else?

Tags: sentence

In my cover letter, I was trying to highlight the fact that I did a class project few years ago: here is what I have:

In 2010, I conducted a project on ``Influence of Economic Indicators'' studying the influence of certain economic indicators on the Stock Market in the United States.

What do you think?

Comment: "Completed" implies that the project was succesfully terminated. Using "conducted" may mean that you leaded the project. "Carry out" is another possibility (meaning either to bring to a successful issue or  to put into execution).

Answer (score 1):

How about

> In 2010, I conducted research on the influence exercised on the US stock market by certain economic indicators. This research culminated in an essay titled *Influence of Economic Indicators*.